# Proguard how to keepclasseswithmembernames recursively?

Tags: java, proguard

For example, if I have an annotation called `com.example.annotation.MyAnnotation` and I would have this proguard:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames public class * { @com.example.annotation.MyAnnotation <fields>; }
```

I would expect all public classes containing `MyAnnotation` would be left alone with proguard. But what if I also want to keep all classes extending that class without also having the same annotation in those classes? For example:

```
public class Example1 {

    @MyAnnotation String myString; 
}

public class Example2 extends Example1 {

}
```

If I understand this correctly, `Example1` will be kept with that proguard line, but I also need to keep `Example2` since its parent class has `MyAnnotation`.